# Java Swing: how do I define how a JTree displays the "user object"?

Tags: java, swing, jtree, treemodel, user-object

When using a `JTree`, a "user object" of a `DefaultMutableTreeNode` can be set. This can be of any kind, but to display it, its `toString()` value is used. This is not what I need.

**How can I change the way a user object is displayed?**

NOTE: My user object *has* to be something different than a `String` to be able to maintain mapping between the tree and the user objects.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't get what's your problem.

The `DefaultMutableTreeNode` will use the `toString` method on the user object because it makes sense. The `JTree` needs strings to draw objects so asking to your object its string rapresentation is ok.

If you really need to avoid calling `toString` on your object you will need a way to provide a string rapresentation of it anyway, but you will have to write your own `MutableTreeNode`:

```
class MyTreeNode implements MutableTreeNode
{
  UserObject yourObject;

  MyTreeNode(UserObject yourObject)
  {
    this.yourObject = yourObject;
  }

  // implement all needed methods to handle children and so on

  public String toString()
  {
    // then you can avoid using toString
    return yourObject.sringRapresentation();
  }
}
```

But I really don't see the point of doing this.. in addition you can try extending the `DefaultMutableTreeNode` by overriding `toString` method, but you will need an additional reference to your object or some *downcasts* will be needed.

If you really need a different visualization than a string you will have to write your own rendered that implements `TableCellRenderer`.

Comment: That was exactly my problem: I didn't know that overriding `DefaultMutableTree`'s `toString()` in this case is the same as overriding `toString()` of the user object (which by the way is final and from an external API, so I couldn't do it).

Comment: If I have a JTree containing Activity objects where an Activity has a Title and a Time field I might use this object in a table where in separate columns I show title and time and use it in a Jtree where I want to show title - time.. however if I have only toString() method to override I cannot satisfy both...

Answer (score 5):

Override toString() on your user object OR provide a [TreeCellRenderer](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/TreeCellRenderer.html), [basic example](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html)

Comment: I'd keep the renderers as thin as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative if you just care about the text shown for the user object and don't want to bother with TreeCellRender:  extend JTree and override [convertValueToText](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTree.html#convertValueToText%28java.lang.Object,%20boolean,%20boolean,%20boolean,%20int,%20boolean%29) with your own code that creates a descriptive string for that object.